# Keeping the Polygons in same size while performing Zoom interaction

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to create Polygons using Openlayers Polygon and trying to keep them in the same size while zooming in and out.
But when I zoom in the coordinates are getting created with huge numbers as I multiply them with resolution.
Can anyone help me?
Below is the code:

```
import {Map,View,Feature} from 'ol';
import {OSM,Vector as VectorSource} from 'ol/source';
import $ from 'jquery';
import {Tile as TileLayer,Vector as VectorLayer} from 'ol/layer';
import {fromLonLat,toLonLat} from 'ol/proj';
import {Polygon,Point} from 'ol/geom';
import {Fill,Stroke,Style} from 'ol/style';
import {Translate,defaults as defaultInteractions} from 'ol/interaction';

//Position of our map center

var pos = fromLonLat([76.87403794962249, 8.569385045000772]);

//Position for our Triangle Polygon

var pos1 = fromLonLat([76.85860825505787, 8.575525035547585]);

//The below line is to check the Longitude and Latitude

var pos2 = fromLonLat([76.85286067404068, 8.56925661298456]);

var pos3 = fromLonLat([76.86300346314657, 8.56917303421666]);

//Position for arrow Polygon

var arrowOne = fromLonLat([76.86219331461274, 8.565926475435887]);

var arrowTwo = fromLonLat([76.86584111887299, 8.566053785302557]);

var arrowThree = fromLonLat([76.86566945749604, 8.56758150037902]);

var arrowFour = fromLonLat([76.87034723001801, 8.56456850087342]);

var arrowFive = fromLonLat([76.86635610300385, 8.562064722566959]);

var arrowSix = fromLonLat([76.86627027231538, 8.5638470749155]);

var arrowSeven = fromLonLat([76.86163541513764, 8.564016822322785]);

//OSM() Tile layer for our Map

var tileLayer = new TileLayer({
    source: new OSM()
});

//Setting View for our Map
var tempCord = [8175188.806634023, 914499.0604405673];
var viewOne = new View({
    center: pos,
    zoom: 10
});

//Coordinates for our Polygons
var cordTriangle = [pos1, pos2, pos3, pos1];
var cordArrow = [arrowOne, arrowTwo, arrowThree, arrowFour, arrowFive, arrowSix, arrowSeven, arrowOne];

var polyTriangle = new Polygon([cordTriangle]);

//To get varying coordinates
var cordArray = [
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
];

//The below function will multiply the cordinates with resolution while zooming

function myFunction() {

    var resol = viewOne.getResolution();
    for (var outer = 0; outer < cordArrow.length; outer++) {
        for (var inner = 0; inner < cordArrow[outer].length; inner++) {

            cordArray[outer][0] = cordArrow[outer][0] * resol;

            cordArray[outer][1] = cordArrow[outer][1] * resol;
        }
    }

    console.log(cordArray);
}


var polyArrow = new Polygon([cordArray]);

//Adding the Feature for our Polygons
var featureTriangle = new Feature({
    geometry: polyTriangle,
    labelPoint: new Point(pos),
    name: 'My Polygon',
    id: 'triPoly'
});

var featureArrow = new Feature(polyArrow);

//vectorSource.addFeature(feature);

var vectorSource = new VectorSource({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    features: [featureTriangle, featureArrow]
});

// The below Select is needed if we have to select a feature before move
//var select = new Select();

//The below will select all the Features and add it for Translate
var translate = new Translate();

//Setting custom styles for our Polygons

featureTriangle.setStyle(new Style({
    fill: new Fill({
        color: 'red'
    })
}));

featureArrow.setStyle(new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
        color: 'cyan',
        width: 4
    }),
    fill: new Fill({
        color: 'red'
    })
}));

var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: vectorSource,
});

// Adding all Layers and creating our Map
var map = new Map({
    interactions: defaultInteractions().extend([ /*select,*/ translate]),
    target: 'map',
    layers: [tileLayer, vectorLayer],
    view: viewOne
});

//To get the Lon and Lat of clicked location over map. This will be displayed in the console.

$(document).ready(function () {
    map.on('click', function (event) {
        let cordClick = toLonLat(event.coordinate);
        console.log(cordClick);
    });
});

/*
$(window).resize(function () {
    $(window).trigger('zoom');
});
$(window).on('zoom', function () {
    console.log('zoom', viewOne.getResolution());
});
*/


//The below  will call myFunction when we zoom

document.getElementById("map").addEventListener("wheel", myFunction);

var featCoord = featureTriangle.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
//featureTriangle.setGeometry('Polygon');
console.log('Geometry Type', featCoord);
```

Comment: Probably needs to be done as an overlay.  Vectors move with the map and scale with it.  Overlays move but don't scale.  If you need to drag an overlay refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038040/can-we-make-ol-overlay-draggable-on-openlayers-3

Comment: @Mike Can we add a feature as an overlay?

Comment: Can anybody provide some help?

Comment: Look at the overlay examples e.g. http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html  You would use a png for your arrow.

Comment: Thanks @Mike for the suggestion.
But my requirement is to use a Polygon and keep it same size while zoom.

Comment: @Mike My aim is to use Polygon site markers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely have to do that way you can't simple multiply the coordinates by the resolution, they would need to re-calculated relative to the opening position and resolution (suggest you open at a higher zoom level for that) and the geometry would need to be reset each time.  Also `pos` would need to be updated when a translate occurs.  You should use `viewOne.on("change:resolution",myFunction);` to catch zoom changes, they won't just happen on wheel events.

These are the changes you will need to get zoom and translate working for the arrow.  pos is the opening position you used in the view, resOne is the resolution of  the initial view setting (I've changed zoom to 13 to make the arrow bigger).  You'll also need to call myfunction to set up cordArray before declaring polyArrow.

```
var viewOne = new View({
    center: pos,
    zoom: 13
});
resOne = viewOne.getResolution();




var transPosArrow = pos.slice();
function myFunction() {

    var resol = viewOne.getResolution();
    for (var outer = 0; outer < cordArrow.length; outer++) {
        // for (var inner = 0; inner < cordArrow[outer].length; inner++) {

            cordArray[outer][0] = transPosArrow[0] + (cordArrow[outer][0] - pos[0]) * resol/resOne;

            cordArray[outer][1] = transPosArrow[1] + (cordArrow[outer][1] - pos[1]) * resol/resOne;
        // }
    }

    console.log(cordArray);
    if (featureArrow) {
        featureArrow.setGeometry(new Polygon([cordArray]));
    }
}

myFunction();
var polyArrow = new Polygon([cordArray]);




//The below will select all the Features and add it for Translate
var translate = new ol.interaction.Translate();
var transStartArrow = [];
translate.on('translatestart', function(evt) {
    for (i=0; i<evt.features.getArray().length; i++) {
        if (evt.features.getArray()[i] === featureArrow) {
            transStartArrow[0] = evt.coordinate[0];
            transStartArrow[1] = evt.coordinate[1];
        }
    }
});
translate.on('translateend', function(evt) {
    for (i=0; i<evt.features.getArray().length; i++) {
        if (evt.features.getArray()[i] === featureArrow) {
            transPosArrow[0] = transPosArrow[0] + evt.coordinate[0] - transStartArrow[0];
            transPosArrow[1] = transPosArrow[1] + evt.coordinate[1] - transStartArrow[1];
        }
    }
});




//document.getElementById("map").addEventListener("wheel", myFunction); // deleted
viewOne.on("change:resolution",myFunction);                             // added
```

Comment: Okay @Mike.
Could you please detail the code as I am new to this and finding it difficult to understand the logic?
Also I need to understand where we are declaring 'resOne' variable and pos[] array.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mike.
It is changing size according to the zoom But it is moving far from the location which it shows initially.Is it mandatory to use position from the View? Also I am having doubt in the translate.on event part.
We are not using transPosArrow array anywhere.
Could you please check this?

Comment: Using the initial view position as an anchor keeps the arrow in the same screen position if you simply zoom in or out without changing the center, but you could use anywhere as the anchor, e.g. the tip of the arrow.  transPosArrow is used when setting cordArray (note that I commented out the "inner" loop to avoid [0] and [1] being updated twice, which did cause excessive movement).

Comment: Sorry.I didn't say it in the right way.What I meant is that when we zoom out the size keeps on increasing and when we zoom in the size is reducing.
Can we keep it in the same size as we render first time? Something similar to overlay which won't change size when we do zoom.

Comment: Thanks
I set the initial pos to the centre of the arrow Polygon.Now it is working fine.
Thanks for the great support :)